# Getting AttributeError: 'SearchResults' object has no attribute 'items' for Twitter API

Tags: python, api, twitter

I'm trying to get tweets from a certain hashtag between a defined amount of time. The code I've compiled is not working due to the error specified below:

AttributeError: 'SearchResults' object has no attribute 'items'

Below is the code:

```
import tweepy
import csv
import pandas
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

csvFile = open('ua.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets,
                           q = "#myquery",
                           since = "2022-01-01",
                           until = "2022-02-01",
                           lang = "en").items():

    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
    print tweet.created_at, tweet.text
csvFile.close()
```

Error code in detail:

```
  File "...", line 20, in <module>
    for tweet in api.search_tweets(q="#myquery").items():
AttributeError: 'SearchResults' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `API.search_tweets` can only match results within the past 7 days, you are requesting Tweets from outside of that period, so the results will be empty.

Comment: thank you! i've worked around the attribute error too and just ran into the issue you mentioned. is there a way of requesting tweets older than past 7 days?

Comment: If you have Academic access you have access to the full archive search, apart from that recent search is 7 days.